How to upgrade kernel on a live Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS system?
I always have in my pocket an USB Stick with the same LTS version all my computer use in order to help my friends whenever they need.
As I often face very recent hardware, I need to have the latest kernel installed on the live system.
This worked well in the past but since Noble, I can't update the initramfs. When I try to install the live-tools package, I get this :
root@ubuntu:~# live-update-initramfs --help
Command 'live-update-initramfs' not found, but can be installed with:
apt install live-tools
root@ubuntu:~# apt install live-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  debian-installer-launcher
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  live-tools
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/26.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 108 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 261972 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../live-tools_1%3a20190831.1_all.deb ...
dpkg-divert: error: 'diversion of /usr/sbin/update-initramfs to /usr/sbin/update-initramfs.orig.initramfs-tools by live-tools' clashes with 'local diversion of /usr/sbin/update-initramfs to /usr/sbin/update-initramfs.distrib'
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/live-tools_1%3a20190831.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 new live-tools package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/live-tools_1%3a20190831.1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@ubuntu:~#

Could you, please, help me getting this fixed ?
Many thanks in advance for your help.
Have a nice and bright day !

This is a bug.
